# Pass ActionBar search query to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, searchview

Here is the seen I have a `SHERLOCK FRAGMENT ACTIVITY` which holds four `FRAGMENTS` and a `SEARCH VIEW`. There are 4 fragments in which last is `FRAGMENT SEARCH RESULTS`

**My question is how to pass data of search query to `FRAGMENT SEARCH RESULTS` from search view and display search result in `FRAGMENT SEARCH RESULTS`**

I implemented this

```
private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
        if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        } else {
            searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        }
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.length() > 0) {
            **//WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE**
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: did you get this working ? cud you pls post your solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.length() > 0) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment newFragment = new SearchFragment(); //your search fragment
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("query_string", query);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();   
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example in here [action-bar-search-view](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/).

To display search result, you need to pass `submitYourQuery(query);` and return true on successful search.

> The process of storing and searching your data is unique to your application. You can store and search your data in many ways. Storing and searching your data is something you should carefully consider in terms of your needs and your data format.

Get the more details from the android documentation [ReceivingTheQuery](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ReceivingTheQuery)

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround you can override this method (startActivity(Intent) ) in your BaseActivity and then check if the action is ACTION_SEARCH then do your special job

```
@Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH))
                // Do ur job here start fragment for Example

             return;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }
```